# Offload data from faker API to json file

Tags: json, api, faker

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from faker import Faker

response_list = []

id = set(range(10000))

fake = Faker()

for i in id:

```
response = {
        "id": i,
        "first_name": fake.first_name(),
        "last_name": fake.last_name(),
        "date_of_birth" : str(fake.date_of_birth()),
        "phone": fake.phone_number(),
        "company_name": fake.company(),
        "company_description": fake.bs(),
        "job": fake.job(),
        "email": fake.email(),
        "user_name": fake.user_name(),
        "credit_card" : {
        "credit_card_number": fake.credit_card_number(),
        "credit_card_provider": fake.credit_card_provider(),
        "credit_card_expire": fake.credit_card_expire(),
    },
        "address": {
        "address_street" : fake.street_address(),
        "address_postal" : fake.postcode(),
        "address_country" : fake.country(),
    },

}
```

response_list.append(response)

app = Flask(**name**)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
return jsonify(response_list)

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: Next to your code please share with us the expected and the actual outcome

Comment: I spect to have a JSON file with 10000 unique records.